# Passing getChildContext() to reactjs higher order components throws unexpected token error in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I got the following example from [HERE](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-react-context-a7592dfdcbc#.8k63wvt27) to make a higher order component for passing context reliably.

However, there is a `Unexpected token` error passing `getChildContext()` function when compiling the script using webpack:

```
getChildContext = () => getChildContext(this.props);
               ^^^
```

Code:

```
const provideContext = 
  (childContextTypes, getChildContext) => (Component) => {
    class ContextProvider extends React.Component {
      getChildContext = () => getChildContext(this.props);

      render() {
        return <Component {...this.props} />;
      }
    }
    ContextProvide.childContextTypes = childContextTypes;

    return ContextProvider;
  };
```

Is there a workaround way of passing the function?

My webpack config:

```
var common = {
    output: {path: BUILD_DIR},
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                include: APP_DIR,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react'),
            'react-dom': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react-dom')
        },
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },

};


config.push(
    merge(common, {
        entry: {
            ItemPage:APP_DIR+'/page/'+fileName+'.js',

        },
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            filename: "[name].js",
            libraryTarget: 'umd',
            library: "[name]"
        },
        externals: [{
            react: {
                root: 'React',
                commonjs2: 'react',
                commonjs: 'react',
                amd: 'react',

            },
            "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
        }]

    })
);

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `Unexpected token` because you are missing one babel plugin, [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which is included in `stage-1` preset

[With stage-1](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-1&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20provideContext%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20(childContextTypes%2C%20getChildContext)%20%3D%3E%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ContextProvider%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20getChildContext%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20getChildContext(this.props)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CComponent%20%7B...this.props%7D%20%2F%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ContextProvide.childContextTypes%20%3D%20childContextTypes%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ContextProvider%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B), it works

[Without stage-1](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20provideContext%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20(childContextTypes%2C%20getChildContext)%20%3D%3E%20(Component)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20ContextProvider%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20getChildContext%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20getChildContext(this.props)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20render()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3CComponent%20%7B...this.props%7D%20%2F%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ContextProvide.childContextTypes%20%3D%20childContextTypes%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ContextProvider%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B), it does not work

So in order to fix it, you have to

1º Install `stage-1`

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1
```

2º Add it to .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react","es2015","stage-1"]
}
```

Or to the webpack config

```
query: {
       presets: ["react","es2015","stage-1"]
}
```